# CVS restore project from local history

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, cvs

We are using CVS in Eclipse. Unfortunately for me we are not allowed to commit on separate branches so i had 2 weeks of uncommitted development.
I was preparing the workspace for the commit when i accidentally replaced the wrong project with latest from head (so i rollback the project to the state before my development).

I know that with the local history of CVS (right click on file, replace with > history... )I can restore the last saved version of a file.

My question is: Is there a possibility to restore all the project together? (not one file at a time)?

If i cannot restore all together, can i find a list of modified files somewhere? (in .CVS ?).

Thank you!

Comment: 'Local History' is not actually CVS, it is a separate Eclipse function. It only goes back a few days (depending on the configuration in the preferences).

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 I found the files of the local history as you said is maintain by an eclipse plugin in this folter project_root\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources. I'm going to make a script or something witch iterate the files and give me the names of the modified files so i can restore them one by one.